# Check Email attachments for specific mail using imaps in java

Tags: java, android

How to check the no. of attachments for the selected mail using imap?

I am able to get the message body/headers but I am not able get the attachment specific to mail selected?

Here is the code I tried:

```
    DataHandler handler = message.getDataHandler();

AttachedFileName= handler.getName();
```

This code will give the filenames of all the attachments in the inbox and not specific to a mail.

How do I go about doing this?

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

you can increase a value for an integer when an attachment is finished.so,number of values increased is number of attachments .
     It's a simple think too ..

Comment: I am asking for specific mail not total mail attachment.